# Building dark mode / iOS 13 app for release (seemingly not possible on Xcode 11 or Xcode 10)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, xcode11

I have an iOS app that I've updated to support Dark Mode in iOS 13. It builds fine in both Xcode 11 beta and Xcode 10 in debug. I am trying to release the app to the app store, and am finding it impossible to build a release version that supports Dark Mode.

If I build in Xcode 10 (having copied in the appropriate Device Support files for iOS 13/13.1 and verified that it compiles), Dark Mode doesn't work.

If I build in Xcode 11, Dark Mode works fine in debug but when I try Product > Archive the build hangs. I tried a billion different things to fix the hang but then read that you can't build for release in a beta Xcode anyway.

So my question is: what is the right way, if any, to release an app that is compatible with iOS 13 right now? Or do I have to wait until Xcode 11 comes out of beta? This doesn't seem likely to be the case because Apple seems to want its developers to have app updates ready and waiting for launch.

Comment: You can't use beta tools to submit an app for release. You can use Xcode 11 beta 7 (nothing earlier) to push a build to Test Flight. Most likely Apple will release the GM version of Xcode and iOS 13 tomorrow. Those updates will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

As rmaddy says above, I needed to wait for GM to release. However, the build hang issue was not caused by this, and actually you should be able to build and upload to testflight using a beta. Since then GM was released and the hanging archive issue persists, I've create a new question specifically for debugging release build issues.